# How can I use multiple icon size in same wizard?

Tags: icons, nsis, wizard

How can I use multiple icon size in same wizard?
I have 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 and 256x256 icon's size and I want to know if i can use them all in nsis?

To use as small, medium and large icons. If I change the view in windows explorer the icon of my setup becomes distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows icon can contain multiple images with different sizes, your icon should ideally contain 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128 and 256x256 pixel images.

You need to use a icon editor to create the .ico. There are [multiple](http://greenfishsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/07/greenfish-icon-editor-pro.html) [free](https://web.archive.org/web/20110426175519/http://icofx.ro/) [icon](http://www.free-icon-editor.com/download.htm) [editors](http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-icon-maker-software/) and [converters](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1227375-ultimate-icon-converter-create-and-convert-ico-files-very-easily/) [out](http://www.falcoware.com/FalcoIconEditorStudio.php) [there](http://www.freewarefiles.com/results.php?categoryid=3&subcategoryid=38&action=sort&sort=rating&currentorder=DESC)...

Comment: but can I use them all in my setup?

Comment: You question does not make sense, a .ico file can contain multiple images so you should pack all your images into one .ico file...